# Determine a branch of $f(z)=\log(2iz−z^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, branch-cuts, branch-points

Determine a branch of $f(z)=\log(2iz-z^2)$ that is analytic at $z=1$. Then find $f(1)$ and $f'(1)$.

First we note that $g(z)=2iz-z^2$ and recall $\mathcal{L}_\tau:=\log|z|+i\arg_\tau z$. So a **branch** we want would be $F(z)=\mathcal{L}_\tau(g(z))$. However, I'm having a hard time understand how to actually do this. I think I have to start by saying $$g(z)=0\implies 2iz-z^2=0\implies z=0, z=2i$$.
OR I have to insert $1$ since that's what we want, which is to say
$$g(1)=2i-1$$
But then I'm unsure of what to do with this information or where to go from here. The $\tau$ and $\mathcal{L}$ really makes stuff wierd, especially $i\arg_\tau z$, because $\arg z$ is something different.

Comment: Since you are reading the book by [Saff-Snider](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4442468/int-z-1ze1-z2dz#comment9301728_4442473), it would be helpful to check Definition 4 (branch) in Section 3.3 and read Example 2 right after the definition.

Answer (score 1):

When we write out $f(1)$ for the single-valued function with branch, it's

$$ f(1) = \mathcal{L}_\tau(g(1)) = \log |2i-1| + i \arg_\tau(2i-1) $$

So $\tau$ just needs to be chosen so that $g(1) = 2i-1$ is not on the branch cut. The usual branch cut along the negative reals with $-\pi < \arg z \leq \pi$ will work fine since $2i-1$ is not real.

Comment: I guess I'm still confused on how to pick the branch. It's somewhat unclear. The definition of a branch doesn't really make too much sense, but then I'm also confused about picking the domain in the complex plane since there's no real way to determine greater than 0 other than positive i values.

Comment: The complex log as a multi-valued function is defined at every point except zero, not just "positive" points. But choosing a single value at each point can never get a function which is continuous everywhere, so the branch cut is a choice of where to let the function be discontinuous.