# How to evaluate the integral $\int_{|z|=1}ze^{1/z^2}dz$ using the residue theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

**Question**:

> Using the Cauchy Residue Theorem, evaluate the integral of
> $$\int_{|z|=1}ze^{1/z^2}dz$$

---

Naturally, we let $f(z)=ze^{1/z^2}$ and expand $e^x$ to get

$$f(z)=z\big(1+\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{2z^4}+\frac{1}{6z^6}+\cdots\big)=z+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2z^3}+\frac{1}{6z^5}+\cdots$$

First note the order of the pole is $2$, so the order of the derivative is $1$.

$$\operatorname{Res}{(f(z),0)}=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{d}{dz}(z\big(z+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2z^3}+\frac{1}{6z^5}+\cdots\big))$$

At this point, I'm confused on what terms I need to kill off, or to what extent do I keep the expansion? Would I just restrict this to become

$$\lim_{z\to0}{2z+1+\frac{1}{2z}}=1$$

or must I consider higher order terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are thinking too hard. You already have
$$
ze^{1/z^2}=z+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2z^3}+\cdots
$$
which tells you by (one main equivalent) *definition* that $\textrm{Res}(f,0)=1$.

You only need other techniques for finding residues when you *don't* know an easy Laurent expansion of the function.

---

> First note the order of the pole is 2.

No, the function has an [essential singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity) at $z=0$, which is not a pole.

Comment: I understand now the Laurent series, but I'm not following the rest. I don't understand the reasoning for the residue being $1$. However, following that, the evaluation of the integral would be $$\int=\frac{1}{2i\pi}$$

Comment: @help: "I don't understand the reasoning for the residue being 1." Do you know the *definition* of "residues" of $f$ at a point? // The integral should be $2\pi i$ if you apply the residue theorem. It is "multiply", not "divide".

Comment: I just found it in the text. It's not worded too nicely, so I read past it a couple times. Using this problem as an example, it makes much more sense now.

Comment: @help. Which book are you reading?

Comment: Saff & Snider - Fundamentals of CA

Comment: @help: Okay.  So it is in Definition 1 of Chapter 6. Your exercise is similar to Example 1 in Section 6.1.

Comment: I accidentally clicked that, I'm following. It's much clearer now. That definition makes the problem easy.

Answer (score 4):

The residue is nothing but  the coefficient of $\frac 1 z$ in the Laurent series expansion which is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

ALTERNATE: If you want to deal with poles only, then 
Put $w=\frac{1}{z}$ so that $dz=-1/w^2 dw$ where $|w|=1$ is unit circle clockwise.
Then $I=\int_{|w|=1} \frac{-e^{w^2}}{w^3}dw=2\pi i\times Res[f(w),0]=\frac{1}{2!}\frac{d^2w}{dw^2}(e^{w^2})=1$